# Pi Historian, Only show result if value equals

Tags: plc, opc, historian

I am using PI Historian to read values from some Tag Points.

I am using this particular Historian software http://www.osisoft.com/

I would like to know if I can get it to show results if contains certain "text" or "result"

Where is says Tag Mask I can put Tag I want search for, after I get that Tag, then I can do a current value or sampled data, or timed, or calculated.

Instead I would like it to show tag which have current value of example "book" Quality tag

Answer (score 4):

"book" would be a digital state string for a digital tag. In order to search for that, you would simply go to the box that says "Value" and click on the right pointing arrow and change it to "Status". You can then enter "book" and it will return a list of all of the tags that have that status.

I apparently don't have enough reputation points to post a screenshot yet.

Comment: Hi, thanks you are right there, is a Statue in drop down menu, I tried changing it Status and tried searching but it didn't return anything, I know there are some values which exist.

Comment: can you please upload screenshots to Tinypic.com and post link here, me or other with higher reputations can change it to image. Thanks alot.